# Get point layer from CSV with coordinates in meters

Tags: qgis, coordinates

QGIS 3.10. Project in WGS 84/UTM zone 41N. Trying to create new point layer from CSV file, where coordinates for X and Y are given in meters (MSK-66 zone 1 - one of local CRS for Russia based on Gauss-Kruger). While doing that through usual: Layer - Add new layer - Add Delimited Text layer I'm getting only the table with missed geometry. This is the example of coordinates I have.

```
390803.41,1535372.18
390809.75,1535399.92
```

Have found one method with online reprogecting original data to WGS84 (https://geobridge.ru), than opening CSV in JOSM, creating geojson, and than back to QGIS, but that's tediously. Is there a simpler solution?

UPD. After Gabriel De Luca question.
That's what I have in the dialog. Now I got geometry, but facing the problem of wrong location of the points.
[image]

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of the CSV import dialog in QGIS? Is the CRS already created (can you choose it, for instance, for the project)?

Comment: @Gabriel De Luca, I'm forced to close the question. When once again I tried to pass through the process the programm converted my data into geometry. I think the problem was in original data. My first several attempts were made with commas instead of dots in coordinates. After that I start trying to use online reprojecting tool and replaced commas by points. Now I have my points in the wrong place, but that's another question...